# Snowflake Driver issue on Big-Endian Platforms

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

We are observing an issue with latest Snowflake JDBC driver where even basic Select queries are failing with below exception. It used to work with earlier version 3.10.3. It seems issue with "Arrow" . Any plans of fixing this issue.
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Arrow only runs on LittleEndian systems.
at net.snowflake.client.jdbc.internal.io.netty.buffer.UnsafeDirectLittleEndian.(UnsafeDirectLittleEndian.java:65)
at net.snowflake.client.jdbc.internal.io.netty.buffer.UnsafeDirectLittleEndian.(UnsafeDirectLittleEndian.java:50)
at net.snowflake.client.jdbc.internal.io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocatorL.(PooledByteBufAllocatorL.java:50)
at net.snowflake.client.jdbc.internal.apache.arrow.memory.AllocationManager.(AllocationManager.java:53)
snowflake-da

Comment: Any update on this?

Comment: Did someone get a chance to review this issue?